# Cómo hacer referencia a archivos DLL en C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, dll

Utilizo varias DLL para mi proyecto. Para usar dichas DLL en Visual Studio las agrego desde la pestaña "Proyecto->Agregar referencias", y al momento de compilar el proyecto donde añadi dicha referencia crea el ejecutable del proyecto y una copia de la DLL.

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer referencia a la DLL pero que este en otra ruta para tener mejor organizado el proyecto , por ejemplo me gustaria que el ejecutable se encuentre en la raiz y las bibliotecas esten en un subdirectorio que se llame "librerias".

El problema es que no encuentro la forma de indicarle a visual studio la ruta de donde se encuentra la DLL.

Answer (score 0):

En la carpeta donde estará el ejecutable puedes crear una carpeta para las librerías, por ejemplo una carpeta llamada "LIBRERIAS". Agrega ahí las DLL que vas a usar. Entonces vuelve a referenciarlas desde esa ruta.
En las propiedades de cada librería , en la opción "Copia Local" selecciona "falso", para que no se copien a la carpeta del ejecutable.

Luego en el archivo de configuración app.config agrega la siguiente linea:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="LIBRERIAS"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

puedes agregarlos despues de la línea de

```
</configSections>
```